# real time decoding of SHVC bit streams

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding, hevc

Does anyone know an open source decoder that can perform real time SHVC bit stream decoding?. The openHEVC states that it has the capability to decode HEVC scalable bit streams, but I was not able to decode a SHVC bit stream generated by SHM 7.0 reference encoder.

Also, does the ffmpeg support scalable extension of HEVC?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [openHEVC](https://github.com/OpenHEVC/openHEVC) current version, seems to be supporting only SHM4.1 bit streams. All layers of the bit streams generated from SHM 4.1 reference encoder are decodable using the current openHEVC version.